# Run External Programms in Java

Tags: java, process, external

I want that my Java Programm 3 external Programms runs. But they should be run NOT in parallel. Programm 1 should output a File, this File is the Input for Programm 2, The output for Programm 2 should be the Input for Programm 3. And the Java Programm should NOT terminate, when the external programms terminate: This is my code but it does not work. Can anyone pls help me!

```
boolean var = true;
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c",
                "start", "C:\\Users\\Rosina\\Desktop\\Riss\\winlibs\\riss3g64", "C:\\Users\\Rosina\\Desktop\\out.cnf", "C:\\Users\\Rosina\\Desktop\\pruv.txt" );
        Process process = processBuilder.start();   
        while(program.exists() && var) {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder3 = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c",
                "start", "C:\\Users\\Rosina\\Desktop\\Riss\\winlibs\\riss3g64", "C:\\Users\\Rosina\\Desktop\\out1.cnf", "C:\\Users\\Rosina\\Desktop\\hahaaaaaaaaaaaaaaafffa2.txt" );
        Process process2 = processBuilder3.start();
        var = false;

        }
```

If Programm 1 has not produce the output, the file program does not exist, and Programm 2 can not start execution...where is my mistake...the code does not work...

Comment: [Process.waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) will help you achieve sequential execution of the programs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait on the process you launched to finish.  You can block the current thread of execution until the process finishes with

```
process.waitFor()
```